# Using CSS Mask Transition with A-Frame sky entity

Tags: animation, aframe

I'm working on a school project and we are developing an interactive story with the A-Frame framework. The idea is to visit your old house and to have memories about good old times. So we're using 360° images in sky entities and we're switching those images between present and past.

I'm working on the transition when switching images, but the only good transition I can develop is a simple fade to black... My idea would be to get something similar to CSS Mask Transition here : https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSSMaskTransition/

Is it in any way possible to get a similar result ?
If not, would you have any idea of a good and easy transition that I could do ?

Just so you know, I'm not used to web development, we only have 3 days to finish this experience and I'm completely new to the A-Frame framework (I've been working on it for 3 days now only).

Thank you very much for you time and have a nice day !

Augustin.

Comment: A transition similar to that will be pretty involved to implement, I don't think it is possible in the span of a couple days with not much graphics experience. You'll mostly likely need to write your own shader that changes the alpha value of each pixel. Or you can maybe create an alpha map GIF or video, and use that to control the alpha values of the texture.

Comment: That's what I was thinking sadly... I have trouble making a simple fade to black transition because I'm using 5 skies superposed. I'm doing that to get a simple animation by changing the opacity of certain skies through CSS instead of using a video (too big) or a gif (quality too poor). Would you have any exemple of animations on skies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transition similar to that will be pretty involved to implement, I don't think it is possible in the span of a couple days with not much graphics experience. You'll mostly likely need to write your own shader that changes the alpha value of each pixel. Or you can maybe create an alpha map GIF or video, and use that to control the alpha values of the texture.

A-Frame has an example for transitioning between 360 images. For better performance, you have one image, do a fade to black, swap out the image, and fade back out: https://github.com/aframevr/360-image-gallery-boilerplate